# How do I get a list of Azure users from Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Basically, I just want to use Microsoft Graph to get a list of active directory users and their email addresses.

Ideally, I could get all the admin users for a certain subscription.

How do I do that? I couldn't find any good examples online.

Comment: By admin user, do you mean Azure subscription Owners? Or Azure AD administrators?

Comment: @juunas I'm not sure if I'll need everyone in my Azure AD, or administrators for the subscription. I think it's the latter. They may be called subscription owners as well, but the portal calls them administrators in at least one place...

Comment: Yeah, the two are different things. One does not imply a role in the other. If it's the latter, you will need to call the Azure Resource Manager API to find the users who have that high-level access at subscription-level: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/listforscope. That will then give you the objectIds of the users. Then you have to call MS Graph API to find the emails for those users: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list or https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the correct access to a tenant, and an authenticated token granting you access to the Microsoft Graph, you can use the following REST API calls to get the data you are looking for:

**List Users** - [Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

**List Admins** (via directory roles) - [Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/directoryrole)

This is a multi-step process. First you must find the directory role for the *Company Administrator*, which will always have the `roleTemplateId` of `62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10`. This should not be confused by the actual directory role `id`, which will be different per directory.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles
```

Then you want to list the users who are a part of that directory role:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/<id>/members
```

If you really need to get started from scratch, I recommend you look at this PowerShell sample I made which simplifies authentication, and allows you to make queries to resource endpoints like the Microsoft Graph.

https://github.com/shawntabrizi/Microsoft-Authentication-with-PowerShell-and-MSAL

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the authentication token to begin with, it seems. If I understand MSAL correctly, it obtains the token by asking for user permission. I however am writing a Windows service which will need its own permissions. So no login prompt -- just silently getting user info from behind the scenes.

Comment: This document explains how you can get access to the Microsoft Graph without a user: [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)